# Contact Us Form Extension not working

Tags: magento-enterprise, contact-us

Let me preface this by the fact that I am 100% new to Magento.

I am trying to extend the contact us page to allow me to add some information to the page, like the form, in which it cannot be change via the CMS (specifically the address information to start).  I have done a ton of google searches and looked at similar questions here (this seems to be the closest: [Contact Us form is not displaying](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15347/contact-us-form-is-not-displaying)) but I am not figuring it out.

I have tried various methods of solving but I am currently trying to add a block.  All I am trying to do at this point is get the "special" text to show on the page along with form. Realize that might be wrong, just looking for some direction on what I am missing.

Code:

**etc/modules/TPW_Contacts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <TPW_Contacts>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </TPW_Contacts>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/TPW/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Contacts') . DS . 'IndexController.php';

class TPW_Contacts_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
?>
```

**app/code/local/TPW/Contacts/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <TPW_Contacts>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </TPW_Contacts>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <contacts>
                <class>TPW_Contacts_Block</class>
            </contacts>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <contacts>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <TPW_Contacts before="Mage_Contacts">TPW_Contacts</TPW_Contacts>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/design/frontend/enterprise/hellov/layout/contacts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="footer_links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="contacts" ifconfig="contacts/contacts/enabled"><label>Contact Us</label><url>contacts</url><title>Contact Us</title><prepare>true</prepare></action>
        </reference>
    </default>

    <contacts_index_index translate="label">
        <label>Contact Us Form</label>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="contacts/location" name="contacts.locationinfo" template="contacts/locationinfo.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </contacts_index_index>
</layout>
```

**app/code/local/TPW/Contacts/Block/Contacts.php**

```
<?php
class TPW_Contacts_Block_Location extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return 'This is my address!';
    }
}
?>
```

**app/design/frontend/enterprise/hellov/template/contacts/locationinfo.phtml**

```
<p><?php echo $this->getLocation(); ?></p>
```

Your help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: Check these files: var/log/system.log, var/log/exception.log, anything under var/reports and also anything under your apache error log.

Comment: Did not have an error but I did have an exception which was cleared up by what Amit Bera and Keyul Shah suggested.

Comment: then revert it and check in all xml file  and php of your instance the code contacts/form.phtml occurs again or not,if it occur more then once then remove second

Comment: Removing the code that Keyul mentioned removes the doubling up of the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue1:Also as you `used  blocks type`  at `contacts/location` so it means this class should be **Mage_Contacts_Block_Location**.

As this  `class not exits`  then  `override` this class  `using another class`

```
<global>
        <blocks>
            <contacts>
                <class>TPW_Contacts_Block</class>
            </contacts>
        </blocks>
    </global>
```

change to

```
 <global>
            <blocks>
                <customcontacts>
                    <class>TPW_Contacts_Block</class>
                </customcontacts>
        <contacts>
            <rewrite>
                <location>TPW_Contacts_Block_Location</location>
            <rewrite>
        <contacts>
            </blocks>
        </global>
```

**Issue2: Other issue with file location:**

As TPW_Contacts_Block_Location if location should be  `app/code/local/TPW/Contacts/Block/Location.php` from `app/code/local/TPW/Contacts/Block/Contacts.php`

**Step3:**
your current `indexAction` did not `set form  post action` .In `default magento from  post action`  is set from  **indexAction function  of Mage_Contacts_IndexController**.If your `rewrite class indexAction` class  `inherit parent class then post action easy come`

**So,you need to change from**

```
public function indexAction()
{

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

to

```
 public function indexAction()
    {
        parent::indexAction();

    }
```

Comment: Made the changes.  Thank you (and Keyul Shah as well).  It is working but now I see the output I added and the form on the page twice.

Comment: give screen.. for check issue

Comment: [Screen Shot](http://www.twobeerdudes.com/images/_remove/doubled_up.png)

Comment: An aside: since I am new to this is there another way that is simpler than I am doing or is this the correct process?

Comment: remove  <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
        </reference> code from contacts.xml for testing

Comment: for study check this http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-override-a-controller-in-magento/

Comment: The page throws out a fatal error: Fatal error: Call to a member function setFormAction() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento\branc....

Comment: just remove  <block type="contacts/location" name="contacts.locationinfo" template="contacts/locationinfo.phtml"/> and remain revert <reference name="content"> <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"/> </reference> forb checking

Comment: No error but still doubling up the form.

Answer (score 0):

In `<frontend>` you are forgot to add the below line.

```
 <layout>
  <updates>
    <contacts>
      <file>contacts.xml</file>
    </contacts>
  </updates>
</layout>
```

So It will not calling your `contacts.xml` file.